# Which backends are consuming Google Container Engine Kubernetes Quotas

Tags: google-app-engine, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to setup an Ingress on Kubernetes on Google Container Engine and am getting quota exceeded errors (see abbrieviated output below).

```
Name:                   my-ingress
Address:
Default backend:        default-http-backend:80 (10.0.2.2:8080)
Rules:
  Host  Path    Backends
  ----  ----    --------
  *
        service1  service1:7010 (<none>)
        service2  service2:6884 (<none>)
Annotations:
  ssl-redirect: false
Events:
  FirstSeen  LastSeen  Count   From                       Type       Reason          Message
  ---------  --------  -----   ----                       --------   ------          -------
  21s        21s       1       loadbalancer-controller    Normal     ADD             reference/reference-ingress
  13s        3s        10      loadbalancer-controller    Warning    GCE :Quota      googleapi: Error 403: Quota 'BACKEND_SERVICES' exceeded. Limit: 5.0, quotaExceeded
```

I know how to increase my quotas, but my question is more specific:  *how can I tell which "backends" are being consumed that are contributing the usage of the quota?* (I will then want to see if I may be able to turn them off if needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-service):

```
gcloud compute backend-services list
```

will list all your backend services in all clusters.
For my case, it lists 6 and match my usage reported by:

```
gcloud compute project-info describe --project PROJECT_NAME
```